# How do I calculate Interest rate (R) from EMI formula if I know EMI, Principal (P) and Time (N)?

Tags: finance, rate, principal

**Hello Guys, How do I calculate tenure (N) from EMI formula if I know EMI, Principal (P) and Interest rate (R)?**

```
Example:
P=50000;
EMI=4368;
N(month)=12
```

What should be the rate(R)?

Comment: sorry for wrong title, it is How do I calculate Interest rate (R) from EMI formula if I know EMI, Principal (P) and Time (N)?

Answer (score 0):

There may be some way to do it with logarithms, don't know

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>

#define TOLERANCE 0.0000001

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::posix_time;

bool active(true);

// just adjust the calc if this isn't the right formula
//
//     EMI = [P x R x (1+R)^N] / [(1+R)^N-1]
//
double calc(double p, double r, double n) {
    return  p * r * pow(r + 1.0, n) / (pow(r + 1.0, n) - 1.0);
}

void timeout_loop() {
    ptime start = microsec_clock::local_time();
    time_duration timeout(seconds(10));

    while(active) {
        boost::this_thread::sleep(milliseconds(1));

        if((microsec_clock::local_time() - start).total_milliseconds() > timeout.total_milliseconds()) {
            cout << "timeout" << endl;
            active = false;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    double p(50000.0);
    double target(4368.0);
    double n(12.0);

    double min(0.0);
    double max(1.0);
    double current = (max + min) / 2.0;

    boost::thread timeout_thread(timeout_loop);

    while(active) {
        double emi = calc(p, current, n);

        if((target - emi) > TOLERANCE) {
            min = current;
            current = (max + min) / 2.0;
        } else if((emi - target) > TOLERANCE) {
            max = current;
            current = (max + min) / 2.0;
        } else {
            cout << setprecision(12) << current << endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    active = false;

    timeout_thread.join();

    return 0;
}
```

0.00733556627529

Answer (score 0):

May be this answer is too late, but hope this can help anyone who is still in search for an answer.

To calculate the rate from EMI, we can use RATE function in Excel.

> RATE(nper,pmt,pv)

nper : ternure of loan in months
pmt : EMI
pv : Principal Amount

If you need Java implementation of this, please refer to below article:

http://www.programmersought.com/article/9304223046/